# How to get the value of a parameter of an actionResult in another actionResult of the same controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It is about the implementation of the reservation in a restaurant.
My structure is as follows. On the home page the customer can click on the restaurant in which he wants to reserve, the system displays the details of this restaurant (with the id which is passed in parmetre. Id which I will wish to recover thereafter)

And on this page the customer can click on the reservation button to go to the reservation form page. I would like the drop-down list of restaurants that is contained in this form to automatically point to the restaurant with which has the previous id.

Or at least if I can retrieve the id I will retrieve its value in the form validation controller and so I can assign the restaurant that corresponds to the reservation before registering the reservation.

Comment: Could you add the relevant code to give us an idea how you have tried approaching it?

Comment: So you want to add the value of a restraurant ID GET parameter to a form?

Comment: I am thinking about the approach I am going to take to the problem. Since I didn't know how to implement it I did some research and found some info on cache usage but it's not really for my project.

Comment: @MaartenDev yes, the value of the parameter

Comment: Did you try passing down the restraurant id to the model in the controller that shows the restraurant page? You could then access the id using the model

Comment: @MaartenDev yes I did it but it didn't work

Comment: Could you explain why that didn't work?

Comment: The drop-down list still does not point to the restaurant. It stays on the first restaurant in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MaartenDev
Here is how I used it. It's the controller of the reservation form

```
public ActionResult Reserver(int id)
        {
            var resto = db.Restaurants.Find(id);
            ViewBag.restoId = new SelectList(db.Restaurants, "resto_id", "name", resto);
            return View();
        }
```